# "?" don't care value in case statement

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use the "?" don't care specifier in my case statement. I have tried using 6'b0001xx and 6'b0001zz as well. I am confused as i have referenced Pong Chu's FPGA prototyping by Verilog examples and it seems he does this the exact same way. When I run the  simulation, when "state" is 0 and "in" is 4 (3'b100) the case statement goes to default instead of the expected first case (6'b0001??). If anybody can explain or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

```
always @(*)
begin
    case({state, in})
        //state0, start is high >> loadA = 1 (s1)
        6'b0001??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b001, {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b0, pass}};
        //state1, start is high >> loadD = 1 (s2)
        6'b0011??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b010, {1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b1, pass}};
        //state2, start is high >> we = 1 (s3)
        6'b0101??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b011, {1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b0, pass}};
        //state3, done is high >> loadA = 1 (s4), done is low >> loadA = 1 (s1)
        6'b01111?: {nstate, nout} = {3'b100, {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b0, pass}};
        6'b0111??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b001, {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b0, pass}};
        //state4, start is high >> loadD = 1 (s5)
        6'b1001??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b101, {1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b1, pass}};
        //state5, start is high >> (s6)
        6'b1011??: nstate = 3'b110;
        //state6, done is low >> loadA = 1 (s4), done is high >> (s7)
        6'b1101??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b100, {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b0, pass}};
        6'b11011?: nstate = 3'b111;
        //state7, finish is low >> increment pass, loadA = 1 (s1), finsih is high >> pass = 0 loadA = 1 (s1)
        6'b1111??: {nstate, nout} = {3'b001, {1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, (pass+1)}};
        6'b1111?1: {nstate, nout} = {3'b001, {1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, 3'b0}};
        default:
            {nstate, nout} = {3'b0, 6'b0};
    endcase
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? fyi, `?` is the same as `z`.

Comment: @Serge I apologize I didnt explain very well. During simulation the case statement goes to the default case when state is 0 and in is 4 (3'100)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are 3 different case statements in verilog: `case`, `casex`, and `casez`. They differ in the way they treat don't cares.

In general, `case` should not have don't care and its behavior is not synthesizable in case of don't cares. The reason is that it does implement the `===` operator to compare conditions. So, it matches x to x and z to z exactly.

With don't care you should either use `casex` and `casez`. Both do symmetrical compare, meaning that `?` is matched to anything, but anything is also matched to '?'. So, there can be false-positives if `state` or `in` in your case contain x or z.

`casez` has a smaller pool of false positives since it only matches 'z', whether casex matches both, 'x' and 'z'. I suggest that you use `casez` for that reason.